# How to get the total count of a Meteor collection with a limit set?

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app, I'm doing infinite scrolling so I must have a limit set on my subscriptions in order to achieve this, but I also need to show the total count from that same collection and update it if the count changes.  How would I achieve that?

I have a partial solution that achieves this but only returns the paginated counts, as follows:

```
function getTotalCount(system) {
    var user = Meteor.user(),
        queryObject = getSystemQueryObject(system);
    if (queryObject) {
        var query = queryObject.find({$and: [
            {user: user.username},
            {status: {$nin: status_complete}}
        ]});

        var count = 0;

        var handle = query.observeChanges({
            added: function (id, user) {
                $('#' + system + 'Count').text(++count);
                $('#' + system + 'Count').addClass("ma-count-badge");
                console.log(system + " count incremented: " + count);
            },
            removed: function () {
                $('#' + system + 'Count').text(--count);
                $('#' + system + 'Count').addClass("ma-count-badge");
                console.log(system + " count decremented: " + count);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The other way is to push this method up to the server as a server method, but then it is not reactive, as follows:

```
    Meteor.call('getSystemsTotalCount', system, function (err, counted) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (counted > 0) {
            $('#' + system + 'Count').text(counted);
            $('#' + system + 'Count').addClass("ma-count-badge");
        }
        Session.get('listLimit');
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to get the count with following way

```
var count= queryObject.find({$and: [
            {user: user.username},
            {status: {$nin: status_complete}}
           ]}).count();
```

after that, you can to save in a Session

```
Session('countCollection',count);
```

if the collection changes your Session also it will do

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too, but the problem is the client only knows the count that it's pulled so far. So in my case, the count is limited to the threshold I have set (20) and therefore, this count will be 20.  I need to know the *total* count from Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

So the trick really is to combine both options I have in the question.  The first part adds reactivity to adds/deletes and the second part calls out to the server to go get the **total** count. Now my code looks like:

```
    query.observeChanges({
        added: function(id, user) { updateListCount(system);},
        removed: function(id) { updateListCount(system);}
    });
```

And I just wrap the `Method.call` from the second excerpt above with a function called `updateListCount` invoked by the above.  This addresses the issue.